# iPad Camera Connection Kit not showing valid MP4 videos

Tags: video, ios, ipad, sd-card

I've been wondering if I can use the camera connection kit as a way to directly copy video files onto my iPad for watching, from SD card. I've tested that photos and videos taken on my digital camera *do* show up on the "import" screen, but when I copy a different MP4 file (an episode of a TV show) into the exact same DCIM directory on the SD card, it is not visible for import. The MP4 was created specifically for iPad using HandBrake - I know if I import into iTunes library they *will* work on the iPad because I've been doing that already - but I'm going away and won't have my Mac with me.

Are there possibly file size restrictions in place, or something else I can easily fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question - the filenames must be in strict 8.3 format i.e. the main name is *exactly* 8 characters long.

Comment: Errrrhm, if it's exactly eight characters long, it's NOT 8.3...

Comment: that depends if you count the extension as part of the length...